# Writing a trigger for every time a user logs in

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I want to write a trigger which runs every time a user logs in and saves the name of each user, for example.

I have written trigger in this way:

```
create or replace TRIGGER LOGON_TRG
AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
BEGIN
INSERT INTO t_log(ID,NAME) VALUES (S1.NextVal,ora_login_user);
END;
```

Does anyone have any solutions for this?

Comment: replace ora_login_user with USER.

Comment: You've told us what you want to happen, you've shown us the code you're using.  But you haven't told us what (if anything) isn't working.  Are you getting an error?  What error?  Is the code not behaving the way you want?  If so, what is it doing (or not doing) that you expect?  Taking a step back, why implement with a trigger what Oracle lets you turn on via auditing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why implement a trigger when Oracle provides you `AUDIT CONNECT`.  It will record the login/logout activity into the audit trail.

You can have a look at Tom's suggestion here https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1830073957439

Comment: That's why is better to search a little bit before start coding like crazy.

Comment: Perhaps that is why we have Stack Overflow ;-)